# Square footage program

Tags: java

I need to create a program in Java that calculates the square footage of a house with 4 rooms. I unsure how to start this as I am new to java. I can choose the dimensions of the rooms so it will not require user input at all. I understand I can use length * width to get the room square footage and than add all four rooms to out.println the house square footage. I am just unsure how to set this all up.

```
public class sqfoot {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        double length, width;
        room1
    }

}
```

this is all I have so far. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: First of all, that isn't valid Java. Secondly, why not ask someone such as an instructor?

Comment: JavaScript is not JAVA.

Comment: thanks alot guys....

Comment: You're guessing, and this never works -- read your text book, notes and a tutorial to learn the most basic rudiments of the language, and then try this again.

Comment: Can anyone recommend a decent tutorial then?

Comment: Google `java tutorial` first hit. Amazing thing, Google.

Comment: you guys are full of jokes tonight... thanks.

Comment: @Rocco_g Jokes aside, you really will receive much better feedback when you ask clear, researched, questions, displaying the effort you put into solving your problem. Stack Overflow is not for teaching you how to program. It is a question and answer forum for helping programmers solve problems when they get stuck. While we understand you are new to programming, there is no shortcut to putting in the time and effort necessary to learn how to program.

Comment: Thank you @Joel Brewer and you're absolutely right. I will keep that in mind next time I ask a question on the forum.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Complete your code with some thing like this :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public static void main(String[] args){

Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

double len = 0;
double wid = 0; 

System.out.print("Enter the length in feet:(##.##) ");

   len = scan.nextDouble();

System.out.print("\nEnter the width in feet: (##.##) ");

   wid = scan.nextDouble();

System.out.print("\n"+"The area is "+wid*len+" square feet.");

}
```

Comment: I have to hard code the dimensions. So would I do something like

Comment: For int you can change the double with int and the scanner with : scan.nextInt ()

Answer (score 0):

This is my elementary answer that I came up with... I am sure there is so many easier ways to do this.

public class sqfoot {
    public static void main(String[] args){

```
    int House1_length1 = 14;
    int House1_width1 = 20;
    int House1_length2 = 10;
    int House1_width2 = 18;
    int House1_length3 = 10;
    int House1_width3 = 17;
    int House1_length4 = 17;
    int House1_width4 = 14;

    int House1_Area = ((House1_length1 * House1_width1) +
            (House1_length2 * House1_width2) +  
            (House1_length3 * House1_width3) + 
            (House1_length4 * House1_width4));

    System.out.println("House 1 square footage is " + ((House1_length1 * House1_width1) +
                        (House1_length2 * House1_width2) +  
                        (House1_length3 * House1_width3) + 
                        (House1_length4 * House1_width4)) + " Sq feet");

    int House2_length1 = 13;
    int House2_width1 = 21;
    int House2_length2 = 12;
    int House2_width2 = 17;
    int House2_length3 = 11;
    int House2_width3 = 15;
    int House2_length4 = 13;
    int House2_width4 = 14;

    int House2_Area = ((House2_length1 * House2_width1) +
            (House2_length2 * House2_width2) +  
            (House2_length3 * House2_width3) + 
            (House2_length4 * House2_width4));

    System.out.println("House 2 square footage is " + ((House2_length1 * House2_width1) +
            (House2_length2 * House2_width2) +  
            (House2_length3 * House2_width3) + 
            (House2_length4 * House2_width4)) + " Sq feet");

    System.out.println("House 1 is larger than house 2 by " + (House1_Area - House2_Area) + " Sq feet");







}
```

}